# Compiling C++.11 using g++ with error does not name a type

Tags: c++11, g++

I'm struggling with `g++` compilation over `c++.11`

Here is the problem I'm facing:

```
error: 'IGameController' does not name a type.
```

The `IGameController` is actually my `class` interface, where I've put the location on my `g++` script.

Here it is my `g++` script to compile:

```
cd C:\MinGW\bin\

g++ -std=c++11 -c c:\Users\me\Downloads\TheGame\TheGame.cpp 
g++ -std=c++11 -Ic:\Users\me\Downloads\TheGame\GameController\inc -Ic:\Users\me\Downloads\TheGame\GameController\src -c c:\Users\me\Downloads\TheGame\GameController\src\GameController.cpp 

g++ -std=c++11 -o c:\Users\me\Downloads\TheGame\TheGame.exe *.o
```

**I don't understand why the script doesn't find my header files...**

My project is structured like this:

```
TheGame\TheGame.cpp
TheGame\GameController\inc\GameControllerProvider.hpp
TheGame\GameController\inc\IGameController.hpp
TheGame\GameController\src\GameController.cpp
TheGame\GameController\src\GameController.hpp
```

Here is my source code:

**[TheGame.cpp]**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GameController/inc/GameControllerProvider.hpp"
#include "GameController/inc/IGameController.hpp"

int main()
{
    GameController::IGameController& gameController = GameController::GameControllerProvider::getGameController();  
    gameController.printSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

**[IGameController.hpp]**

```
#pragma once

namespace GameController
{
class IGameController
{
public:
    virtual void printSomething() = 0;

protected:
   IGameController() {}
   virtual ~IGameController() {}
};

}
```

**[GameControllerProvider.hpp]**

```
#pragma once

namespace GameController { class IGameController; }

namespace GameController
{

    namespace GameControllerProvider
    {
       IGameController& getGameController();
    }

}
```

**[GameController.hpp]**

```
#pragma once

#include "GameController/inc/IGameController.hpp"

namespace GameController
{

class GameController : public IGameController
{
public:
    GameController();
    virtual ~GameController();

    void printSomething() override;
private:

};

}
```

**[GameController.cpp]**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GameController/inc/IGameController.hpp"
#include "GameController/src/GameController.hpp"
#include "GameController/inc/GameControllerProvider.hpp"

namespace GameController
{

GameController::GameController() {}
GameController::~GameController(){}

void GameController::printSomething()
{
    std::cout << "printSomething()" << std::endl;
}

}

// Provider 
IGameController& GameControllerProvider::getGameController()
{
   static GameController sGameController;
   return sGameController;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with namespaces, but for sure one of your problems is with the `#include` statements, where you give a wrong path to some files.

For instance, when you call `IGameController.hpp` (in inc/) from `GameController.cpp` (in src/), since you are using quoations marks (`" "`), you should give the full path to the file, and it  should be written as:

```
#include "../inc/IGameController.hpp"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Eugene. That is not the issue, but you are right, the include was wrong. The error on the compilation remains:(

Comment: I'm just guessing, but maybe the problem is that `IGameController& GameControllerProvider::getGameController()` definition in `GameController.cpp` is out of the namespace. Could you try to move the bracket symbol ( } ) closing the namespace to the end of the file?

Comment: actually you are right:) the problem was that I was using wrong #include's. I thought I had to put the full path every time. But for includes that are already inside the folder, it's just the relative path. I will put your answer as the correcto one!